# PHP cookies issue, not including language file

Tags: php

I have a piece of code that should redirect user if there's no cookies in the session..

```
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    if (in_array($_GET['lang'], $jezici)) {
        $lang = $_GET['lang'];
        // register the session and set the cookie
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
        setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
    } else {
        $lang = 'hr';
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
        setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
    }
} else if (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
} else if (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
} else if (empty($_GET['lang']) || !isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $trenutni_file = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    ?>
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://<?php echo $domena; ?>/<?php echo       $trenutni_file; ?>?lang=hr">
    <?php
    exit();
}
?>
```

This is how I include it in index.php

```
$langArray = include 'lang/'.$lang.'.php';
```

But sometimes I get this error failed to include lang/.php ... This code is obviously not doing everything right.. If no cookie is set in the session I would redirect user to `index.php?lang=hr`... Any help?

Comment: There is no `include` in the posted code. Are you sure the language variable is set when it is executed?

Comment: @user3002173 put that example code into your question, not a comment. Also, are you correctly using `session_start()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last condition   `(empty($_GET['lang']) || !isset($_GET['lang']))`  is redundant itself, since `empty` already checks if the function is set, as you can read [here](http://php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php). Also, it is redundant with the first condition.

Moreover, you are lacking a condition to determine if in the case the var is set in session or cookie, it actually is not empty (it could be set as an empty string, for example)

I would change all your `isset` calls for an `empty` call, and add a final, standalone condition, to chek if $lang is set, no matter how, and if it has a valid value

```
if (!empty($_GET['lang'])) {
    if (in_array($_GET['lang'], $jezici)) {
        $lang = $_GET['lang'];
        // register the session and set the cookie
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
        setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
    } else {
        $lang = 'hr';
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
        setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
    }
} else if (!empty($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
} else if (!empty($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}


if (empty($lang) ||  (!in_array($_GET['lang'], $jezici)))  {
        $trenutni_file = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        ?>
        <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://<?php echo $domena; ?>/<?php echo       $trenutni_file; ?>?lang=hr">
        <?php
        exit();
    }
```